# Why is my C# nested for loop slow?

Tags: c#, performance, xna, nested-loops, monogame

I'm creating a Game as a school project and thought it would be a good idea to use colormapping for level creation, however the method I'm using is *very* slow for some reason.

```
        public List<Entity> LoadLevel(Level level)
    {
        List<Entity> ents = new List<Entity>();
        Color[] clrs = new Color[level.getColorMap.Height*level.getColorMap.Width];
        level.getColorMap.GetData(clrs);
        for (int x = 0; x < level.getColorMap.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < level.getColorMap.Height; y++)
            {
                if (clrs[x + y * level.getColorMap.Width] == new Color(0, 0, 0))
                {
                    ents.Add(new Terrain(new Vector2(x, y)));
                    ents.Last().Animation.setImageIndex(0);
                    ents.Last().Animation.Play();
                }
                if (clrs[x + y * level.getColorMap.Width] == new Color(6, 6, 6))
                {
                    ents.Add(new Terrain(new Vector2(x, y)));
                    ents.Last().Animation.setImageIndex(6);
                    ents.Last().Animation.setSpeed(69);
                    ents.Last().Animation.Play();
                }
                if (clrs[x + y * level.getColorMap.Width] == new Color(9, 9, 9))
                {
                    ents.Add(new Terrain(new Vector2(x, y)));
                    ents.Last().Animation.setImageIndex(9);
                    ents.Last().Animation.setSpeed(69);
                    ents.Last().Animation.Play();
                }
            }
        }
        return ents;


    }
```

I call this function in LoadContent() and it takes about half a minute to execute, why is it so slow?

Comment: This is better suited to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: How big is `level.getColorMap.Height` and `level.getColorMap.Width`?

Comment: They're both 2048 big.

Comment: We have no idea what all those Animation methods do. Comment all lines that start with "ents.". It it helps, the problem is not in this code.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek It could be in this code. `getColorMap` may be loading the colour map from disk, for example. You're right that the 'cost' is external to this code, but it's still something that can be improved here. In any case, it's somewhat of a smell to continually access `level.getColorMap` and `level.getColorMap.Width` instead of storing it in a local variable. Also, the lack of `else if` instead of redundant calculations.

Comment: level.getColorMap returns a Texture2D object which is stored in the level object at startup.

Answer (score 0):

I have some notes to the coding style. Most probably it is not cause of your problems, but better know sooner than later. Generally speaking, you should avoid doing duplicated and unnecessary work. I would not even call it optimization, I would call it a rule. It should be the way you always code.

- What if `level.getColorMap` takes a while? You call it over and over again even when you do not need to do that. You should generally not rely on the fact, that property is cheap. Call it once and remember its result.
- `ents.Last()` is quite fast, but not for free. Do not call it if you do not need it. Build new terrain and remember pointer to it.
- The new `Color(0, 0, 0)` in every loop is bad. Do not take loop hoisting as granted. Most probably you would construct 12000000 color object even when You actually need three.
- Your code also has a lot of duplicity. Generally, think twice before you copy and paste code. DRY
- The loop order is bad. You jump from row to row ruining the cache locality. You should process the whole row and then go to next.
- Avoid multiplication when You need just addition.

Example of improvement:

```
public void AddTerrain(List<Entity> ents, int selector, int x, int y)
{
    Terrain newT = new Terrain(new Vector2(x, y));
    ents.Add(newT);
    var animation = newT.Animation;
    animation.setImageIndex(selector);
    if (selector > 0)
    {
        animation.setSpeed(69);
    }
    animation.Play();
}



public List<Entity> LoadLevel(Level level)
{
    List<Entity> ents = new List<Entity>();
    var colorMap = level.getColorMap;
    int colorMapWidth = colorMap.Width;
    int colorMapHeight = colorMap.Height;
    Color[] clrs = new Color[colorMapWidth * colorMapHeight];
    Color[] colors = new Color[] { new Color(0, 0, 0), new Color(6, 6, 6), new Color(9, 9, 9) };
    colorMap.GetData(clrs);

    int ci = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < colorMapHeight; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < colorMapWidth; x++)
        {
            Color c = clrs[ci++];
            for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (c == colors[i])
                {
                    AddTerrain(ents, c.R, x, y);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ents;
}
```

Comment: Very nice recommendations. Inverting the x and y loops is probably the biggest change. Cache is a very important thing.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The problem was actually in the constructor of the terrainobject, the function for creating its collider was appearantly very poorly optimized, thanks for the help!